# Scrolling Toolbar Behaviour ,with RecyclerView in Frame Layout

Tags: android

I would like for my Toolbar to collapse and reappear, based on when I am scorlling either up or down in my recycler view.

My recycler view gets added when I load a fragment into a FrameLayout container (left_container) on start up. It seems that I can not get this to work, and it does nothing.

Here is the XML for my Activity...

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:elevation="8dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/topToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/left_container"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"></FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/right_container"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0"></FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_draw"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer" />
```

And here is the XML for my Fragment.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would very much appreciate it! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is wrong. The `CoordinatorLayout` must be parent of views with behaviors. You have `RelativeLayout` as a child of `CoordinatorLayout`. I suggest you to read [this article](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en) with a lot of examples about AppBar scrolling behaviours

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Coordinator layout in your fragment and AppBarLayout and its child(toolbar) just inside SwipeRefreshLayout. The scrollable behaviour is achieved if the recycler view and AppBarLayout are the immediate childs of coordinator layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
 android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout             
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

         <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
          android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
          app:elevation="8dp">

              <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
               android:id="@+id/topToolbar"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
               android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
               app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

         </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
         android:id="@+id/recyclerList"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>`
```